# mahout fpg algorithm is not generating frequent patterns file

Tags: apache, mahout

We are trying to find frequent patterns using `Apache Mahout` algorithm. First we ran mahout `fpg` for a subset of our original input file(of size 270 MB) and got  `fList`, `fpgrowth`, `parallelcounting` and `frequentPatterns` files/folders generated. Then we ran `Mahout` `fpg` for complete file which is of 10 GB size and with 268,752 unique features and 201590007 lines. However, `frequentPatterns` files are not generated. It generated `fList`, `fpgrowth` and `Parallelcounting` files. There are no exceptions in logs. Job status is "success".

As per my understanding `Mahout FPG` program sequences three map reduce programs (`ParallelCounting`, `FPGrowth`, `Aggregator`). For some reason, when I run this program on our complete file, it is not starting `Aggregator`, which is supposed to generate `FrequentPatterns` file. I have added some loggers to see what's happening, regenerated the jar file, and re-ran `mahout` on our complete file. There are no exceptions and logs after `startParallelFPGrowth()` do not print.

We are using the configurations below on a three node hadoop cluster.

```
 mahout fpg -i mahoutFPGInput/mahoutFPGOnlineInput.dat -o fpgOutput -k 100 -s 100 -g 20000 -tc 10 -method mapreduce
```

Has anyone come across similar issue?